# Auto update export

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Spreadsheet with several events and two tables.

- Table A contains all data and a function, which checks based on the current time if an event is in the past or in the future. If it is in the future, the value based on current date/time is "show", if it is in past the value changes to "hide"
- Table B contains a filter function to get only the lines with "show" from Table A

The function is:

```
=FILTER(tablea!A:D;table!B:B="show")
```

Until here everything works perfectly. Values were updated automatically, even if I don't change anything manually.

Now I export Table B as JSON. My problem is, when in Table A the value in Column B changes to "show", it also updates in Table B - but the export does not update. Only when I change something manually, it gets a new update.

I already tried:
- include a column with "now()" in Table B to get changing values
- set settings to update every minute

But still, the export only changes, when I change something manually.

Comment: For example, is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56462700/7108653

Comment: Exporting to JSON isn't a built-in Google Sheets feature. How are you doing that?

Comment: @Tanaike this could solve, I would like to test. But where do I implement it? Is this a google app script? If yes, how is it connected to the spreadsheet? I only see a connection to a sheet name?

Comment: @Tanaike I just create a new google app script now and changed the name of the sheet. But the error occurs: TypeError: Method "getSheetByName" from zero cannot be called. (line 4, file "Code", project "recaluclate")

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't understand about your current script and ``line 4, file "Code", project "recaluclate"`` soon. This is due to my poor skill. If I could understand about the reason of your issue, I would like to comment it. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: @Tanaike "line 4" of the script - "recalcualte" is the name I gave to the google app script. So, google tells me, that there is an issue in line 4 of the script with the method "getSheetByName"

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. If I could correctly understand your script and your current issue, I would like to think of the solution and comment it. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon.